# CF11 upgrading to Apache2.4: "mod_websocket.so is garbled"

Tags: apache-2.4, coldfusion, connector

For security reasons, I was informed that I needed to upgrade Apache 2.2 to Apache 2.4, which would take care of OpenSSL vulnerabilities (SWEET32).

I stopped Apache 2.2, disabled it, installed Apache 2.4 (and updated the references in the relevant .conf files to the new Apache24 directory). Installed Apache 2.4 as a service (it shows up in IIS Manager), but it won't start. Instead, it gives me the following error message:

> D:\Apache24\bin>httpd.exe -k install
>   Installing the 'Apache2.4' service
>   The 'Apache2.4' service is successfully installed.
>   Testing httpd.conf....
>   Errors reported here must be corrected before the service can be started.
>   httpd.exe: Syntax error on line 669 of D:/Apache24/conf/httpd.conf: Syntax error
>   on line 1 of D:/ColdFusion11/config/wsproxy/1/mod_wsproxy.conf: API module stru
>   cture 'websocket_module' in file D:/ColdFusion11/config/wsproxy/1/mod_websocket.
>   so is garbled - expected signature 41503234 but saw 41503232 - perhaps this is n
>   ot an Apache module DSO, or was compiled for a different Apache version?

I've removed the connectors using `wsconfig.exe` and reinstalled, re-booting the server in between, and still the same error.

Is there anything I can do about that `mod_webocket.so` file?

Answer (score 0):

Since mod_websocket isn't included in the Apache 2.4 standard distribution (it's a third party module), it wasn't upgraded when you updated your server. It needs to be recompiled.

The steps to do that depend on how you installed mod_websocket in the first place. If ColdFusion distributed the binary to you directly, you'll need to ask them for an updated version; otherwise you need to re-run whatever configuration step produced the module for 2.2.

*Disclosure: I maintain an updated fork of the original mod_websocket.*